# How to use "implementation(s)" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

I am always stuck on certain kinds of sentences while writing.

Which of these would be more correct in a sentence?

> the implementation of applications is available

or

> the implementations of applications are available

Comment: Are you trying to say, "The source code for these applications is available [upon request]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Implementation" in the singular form sounds much more natural to me, unless you have a **very** specific need to refer "multiple implementations". The plural form exists, but I would say it's less common.

Consider these two examples to choose the best option for you:

> The implementation of all the educational applications was successful.
>
> The various implementations of updated, modern systems have proved worthy to businesses in the area.

The singular form is more common, and the plural only seems natural when you need to be insist that more than one implementation is in question.

Comment: thank you @JMB !, what if I say "The implementation of which was successful" based on your text, it will be correct?

Comment: Absolutely! It sounds fine to me.

Comment: But why not just call it a *successful implementation*?  For example instead of saying, 'here is a program, the implementation of which was successful." just say,"Here is a successfully implemented program."